# Запись в массив строк. Сравнение

Tags: c++, linux

Суть моей задачи:

1. Получение данных из файла. Мы заполняем массив logfile всеми логинами из файла, массив logpass заполняется паролями.
2. Цикл, в котором проверяется введенный пользователем логин и пароль, даже если данные из массива нашлись, нужно проверить номер элемента массива. 
   Моя проблема в том,что не удаётся правильно записать данные из файла.Также, возникла сложность с проверкой номера элемента. Буду признателен за советы.

```
char logfile[100];
char logpass[100];
while (!fout.eof())
{
fout >> logfile;
fout >> logpass;
fout.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
};

int n = strlen(logfile);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  if(strcmp(logfile,login))
  {
     cout << "Данные совпадают." << endl;
  }
  else
     cout << "\033[1;31mПользователя не существует.\033[0m" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Почему я не использую map или vector?  Потому что,  данных в файле не так уж  много.

Comment: Ну дак получается вы создали две строки размером на 100 символов и постоянно туда что то записываете в эти две строки

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте так - если хотите все собрать в одну строку:

```
string logfile;
string logpass;
for(string l,p; fout >> l >> p;
    fout.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n')) {
    logfile += l + " ";
    logpass += p + " ";
}
```

Так вы избегаете неприятностей:

1. С ограниченной длиной строк `logfile` и `logpass`.
2. С неверным определением конца файла (признак конца файла устанавливается только **после** неудачной попытки чтения за концом файла. Если вы просто дочитаете до конца файла (не за него) - `eof()` вернет `false`.

Comment: Насчёт, `eof()` учту.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказали в комментариях вы просто перезаписываете переменные  `logfile` и `logpass`.

Перепешите вывод из файла примерно так:

```
std::vector<std::string> logins;
std::vector<std::string> pass;

std::ifstream f( "file.txt" );
while (!f.eof())
{
    std::string tmp;

    f >> tmp;
    logins.push_back(tmp);

    f >> tmp;
    pass.push_back( tmp );
}
```

Comment: Только не так - `while (!f.eof())` - так ваша последняя запись будет неверной.

Comment: Цикл с предусловием !eof - практически всегда ошибка. В С и С++ признак eof никогда так не используется. Он для этого не предназначен. В вашей программе на должно быть проверки eof.